# Why is my radiator not getting hot?

Tags: plumbing, central-heating

I have S-Plan system.  The heating valve has two loops, upstairs and downstairs. There is also a single downstairs radiator connected to the loop before the valve.

The issue started after we replaced our old boiler, a Potterton RS60 floor standing boiler with a Glow-worm Easycom 25r, the radiator connected direct to the boiler loop does not get hot.

Also the downstairs radiators were only partially getting warm.

Things I've tried:

- removed the radiator and flushed it with a pressure washer in the
  garden.
- Replaced the water pump, this resulted in the downstairs radiators not getting any heat. after i partially closed the upstairs TRVs they are now heating up fine so it is likely the old pump was not faulty.

Is it worth moving the pump closer to the boiler downstairs as indicated by red arrow in the picture? or any other ideas to solve this?

[image]

Comment: air in the system

Comment: As said by Traveler,  You need to bleed the air out of the system, especially at each radiator.